# "Safe" Arithmetic of float numbers containing whole number on CUDA

Tags: cuda

I am currently making some research on using float numbers instead of integers on CUDA for arithmetic operations. The necessity arises since integer arithmetic is very slow compared to floating point arithmetic, and thus there is possible performance enhancement when using floats instead of integers.

I've made a small experiments and written a simple program that just loops and adds 1.0f to a variable..It came out that this works up to 16777216.0f ..adding further 1.0f to the number will leave the number unchanged... So I was wondering weather this number is the maximum number which as far as operators +,-,* involving solely whole numbers will lead to accurate whole number results, say with +/-0.0001 accuracy?

Regards
Daniel

Comment: I think you need to read up on floating point arithmetic a little bit; some good starting points are http://floating-point-gui.de/ , http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point , and the canonical reference (complete but challenging), http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html .    Above, you've discovered the idea of machine epsilon (more or less).   I also think you're mistaken about floating point arithmetic being faster than integer arithmetic on GPUs, although for particular use cases floats may well be easier/faster.

Comment: @Jonathan As documented in The Cuda C Programming Guide Table 2 integer multiplications are 6x slower then floating point numbers

Comment: Fair enough; if you have a new enough card and the data is ready to go, there is a big throughput gain to be had.

Comment: ..unfortunately, you'll have to deal with the fact that a 32-bit ieee 754 floating point number can exactly represent integers up to 24 bits, but beyond that the representations are different and so the math becomes different.

Comment: What is the application context in which you wish to replace integer computation with floating-point computation? What is the GPU? The relative throughput of various floating-point and integer operations differs between GPUs. For example, on a C2050 one can execute 515.2e9 single-precision FMADs per second, or 257.6e9 32-bit IMADs per second. Each FMAD or IMAD represents two arithmetic operations.

Answer (score 2):

Jonathan Dursi pointed to some important links to explain floating point in his comment.

If you look, you'll note that 16777216 is 2^24. Floating point (single precision) has 23 bits plus the implicit '1' (since values are normalised). With 24 bits you would be able to represent any integer from 1.0 * 2^0 to 1.11..11b * 2^23 (actually you get the negative numbers too since the sign bit is separate, and zero with special coding). You get the extra value (2^24) since that can be represented as 1.0 * 2^24.

As soon as you try to add 1 to 2^24 you will observe that you are subject to the rounding error described in the links Jonathan posted.

So for integers, you will need to restrict your range to [-2^24,2^24]. If you cannot do that, you either need some careful checking or else restrict yourself to integers!

Comment: Actually that's very good news. So does this mean that if one keeps within the specified range then the operator == can be used.. ?Because if true it is fantastic then. 16777216 is not a huge number but is not at all small and for most usual purposes (indexing specially ) it should be enough.

Comment: Keep in mind, if you're going to be using these as indices for something that in the end requires an integer (eg, array indices), you're going to end up also having to perform that operation, and according to the same table, the potential throughput *there* is comparatively limited.